Can the lexical plugins written by vanilla JS and react re-implement each other
I've been studying lexical for a few days and found that the official playground plugins are written in react, so I wondered if they could be implemented entirely in vanilla JS without state management and default returns
I want to know the difference between the vanilla JS plugin and the react plugin
